# Wagtail migration error with custom user models

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a fresh install of wagtail. To make a user profile page, I want to extend the user data. I added an app with manage.py startapp and followed the official documentation:

https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/custom_user_models.html

I added app profiel, and my model looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class Profiel(AbstractUser):
    bedrijfsnaam = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
    omschrijving = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True)
```

My settings like this:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'profiel.Profiel'
```

The error I get when I migrate is this:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency profiel.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

I found a topic online, advising to temporarely comment out django.contrib.admin in settings.py, but this leads to other errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error suggests that you've already run `./manage.py migrate` before adding your custom model and migration. This is incorrect - your migration for adding a custom user model needs to be part of the initial migration run. [Adding a custom user model to an already-built database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project) is a much trickier process.

If this is a fresh install, your best bet is to delete and recreate the database (by deleting the `db.sqlite3` file if you're using sqlite, or running `dropdb databasename` / `createdb databasename` on postgres) - running `./manage.py migrate` with your new migration in place should then complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can run only one migration rather than all: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate

Therefore, adapt and run the following command:

```py
django-admin migrate [app_label] profiel.0001_initial
```

If that does not work out of the box, add the `--fake` flag as per the docs above.

Comment: Don't use the `--fake` flag unless you're sure you know what's happening at the database level! If a migration makes a meaningful database change (as the profiel.0001_initial one does) but you skip it with `--fake`, that'll lead to a broken database that's hard to recover from.

Comment: That's not what --fake does.

Comment: I tried your solution with and without fake flag. Both resulted in the same error.

Comment: --fake records the migration as having been applied, without making the database change - that's what I mean by 'skipping'. It's intended for use when you've made the change through some other route - e.g. a manual fix to the database. If you use it here _without_ also applying the change manually, you'll end up with a missing `profiel` table and no way to fix it through applying or rolling back migrations (since the migration history indicates that the table should exist).